# import core.std to plugin of frama-c

Tags: makefile, ocaml, frama-c, ocamlfind

I have other problem, I have tried change Makefile for include Core.Std, I would like to use it, for the module List.

This is my MakeFile.

```
FRAMAC_SHARE :=$(shell frama-c-config -print-share-path)
FRAMAC_LIBDIR :=$(shell frama-c-config -print-libpath)
PLUGIN_ENABLE:=$(ENABLE_DTN_ANNOTATION)
PLUGIN_NAME:=Dtn
PLUGIN_DIR:=./
PLUGIN_CMO:= deps_neo
PLUGIN_REQUIRES = core
include $(FRAMAC_SHARE)/Makefile.dynamic
```

When I use "make" this is error:

```
ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
```

In Real Open World Ocaml, it used: 
ocamlfind ocamlc -linkpkg -thread -package core

How can I simulate it in frama-c?

Comment: One thing that may help is adding `VERBOSEMAKE=y` when running Frama-C's Makefile (e.g. `make VERBOSEMAKE=y`). It should output some information about the commands being executed. Then you can try to find out where to add the necessary flags, by reverse engineering. However, Frama-C's Makefile is quite complex, so this will not necessarily be easy.

Comment: As a tip, you can use core_kernel, that doesn't require the threading.

Comment: thanks, with core_kernel, I have the modules I want it.